# How to access the ASP.NET / IIS ContextId

Tags: asp.net, iis, etw

I've seen way too many times in my event logs this "ContextId" for a given ASP.NET request. I've recently started looking into ETW events that are pushed out by ASP.NET, and want to re-use this ContextID in my own events that I fire.

How can I do this?

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentContext doesn't seem to have it. It's always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poorly documented feature, but yes you can get it.

It sits on the HttpWorkerRequest RequestTraceIdentifier property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.requesttraceidentifier.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the `HttpWorkerRequest.RequestTraceIdentifier` property.  Note that obviously you need to have the IIS ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) feature enabled or this property will be `Guid.Empty`.  The following is how to get it from `HttpContext`:

```
var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)HttpContext.Current;
var workerReqest = (HttpWorkerRequest)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
var requestId = workerReqest.RequestTraceIdentifier;
```

Reference: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/commit/b289dbcde3e0f7366d90daf66e00c94f4cc58de3#diff-4934d624fc1d467b08411d520972e840R48